# How to delete image in database and path in codeigniter

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter

I have an image upload form and I have uploaded the image successfully and tried deleting the image, but it deletes only database and I don't know how to delete the path.(how to use unlink) 
here my code

```
     function deleteconf($data){
         $update_id=$this->uri->segment(3);
         $query= $this->_delete($update_id);
         redirect('banner/manage');
     }

    function upload(){ 
     if($this->input->post('upload')){
       $data['banner_name']    =$this->input->post('banner_name',TRUE);
       $data['banner_img1']    =$_FILES['files']['name'][0];
       $config=array(
        'allowed_types' => 'jpg|jpeg|png|gif',
        'upload_path' => $this->gallery_path,
        'max_size' => '2000'
        );

        $this->load->library('upload');
        $this->upload->initialize($config); 
        if($this->upload->do_upload()){
              $data['images']=$this->save_gallery($data);
            }else{
            echo $this->upload->display_errors();
        }
        $image_data=$this->upload->data();
    }
        $data['images']=$this->get_images();
        $data['view_file']='banner_form';
        $this->load->module('template');
        $this->template->one_col_temp($data);
}
```

Comment: I don't see attempt to unlink in your example

Comment: i don't how to use unlink

Comment: try this: `unlink(base_url("folder_path/file_name"));`

Comment: @Arul So you obviously stumbled upon `unlink()` but didn't bother to read documentation or attempt to use it at all?

Answer (score 1):

You can use unlink and pass it your image path 
for example

```
@unlink('MY_UPLOAD/file1.jpg');
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this one

```
@unlink(PATH_DIR.'uploads/xyz.jpg');
```